# Is it a rule that unapply will always return an Option?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, pattern-matching

I tried to create an `unapply` method to use in pattern matching, and I tried to make it return something different than `Option`, however, Eclipse shows that as an error. Is it a rule that `unapply` must return an `Option[T]` ?

EDIT: here's the code I'm trying to use. I switched the code from the previous section so that `unapply` returns a Boolean

```
import java.util.regex._

object NumberMatcher {
  def apply(x:String):Boolean = {
    val pat = Pattern.compile("\\d+")
    val matcher = pat.matcher(x)
    return matcher.find
  }

  def unapply(x:String):Boolean = {
    val pat = Pattern.compile("\\d+")
    val matcher = pat.matcher(x)
    return matcher.find
  }
}

object x {
  def main(args : Array[String]) : Unit = {
    val strings = List("geo12","neo493","leo")
    for(val str <- strings) {
      str match {
        case NumberMatcher(group) => println(group)
        case _ => println ("no")
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Eclipse says `wrong number of arguments for object NumberMatcher`. Why is that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want to return something with `unapply`, return it inside `Some`. Returning `Boolean` just tests if the match can be made or not.

Here is how a pattern matching is translated:

```
str match { 
  case NumberMatcher(group) => println(group)
  case _ => println("no")
}
```

Assuming `NumberMatcher` returns `Option[...]`, it will do:

```
val r1 = NumberMatcher.unapply(str)
if (r1 != None) {
  val group = r1.get
  println(group)
} else {
  println("no")
}
```

If `NumberMatcher` returns Boolean, then you can have it receive something. In that case, this is what happens:

```
str match { 
  case NumberMatcher() => println("yes")
  case _ => println("no")
}
```

becomes

```
val r1 = NumberMatcher.unapply(str)
if (r1) {
  println("yes")
} else {
  println("no")
}
```

Note that this is a *very superficial* explanation. Case matches can test for constants, have additional guard conditions, alternatives, use `unapply` recursively, use `unapplySeq`, etc. Here I'm only showing very basic usage to address a specific question. I strongly advise searching for a fuller explanation of pattern matching.

Answer (score 8):

Take a look at this [example](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/112) again.
I quote

> The return type of an unapply should be chosen as follows:
>       * If it is just a test, return a Boolean. For instance case even()
>       * If it returns a single sub-value of type T, return a Option[T]
>       * If you want to return several sub-values T1,...,Tn, group them in an optional tuple Option[(T1,...,Tn)].

Comment: Can you show me what I should modify in order for the unapply that returns a Boolean to work?

Comment: You can't extract an argument when returning booleans. It's just `case NumberMatcher() => ...`.

Answer (score 1):

When you defined `unapply` to return a `Boolean`, you were indicating that the pattern doesn't have any wildcards to match (or bind). So the case statement for this unextractor should be `case NumberMatcher => println(str)`, and giving it a variable to fill is wrong.

Alternatively, to make `case NumberMatcher(group) => println(group)` you need to define `unapply()` to return `Option[String]`

Answer (score -2):

```
package com.tutorial.extracters
object ExtracterwithBooleanReturnType extends App {
import java.util.regex._
object NumberMatcher {
  def apply(x: String*) = {
    x
  }
  def unapply(x: String): Option[Boolean] = {
    val pat = Pattern.compile("\\d+")
    val matcher = pat.matcher(x)
    return Some(matcher.find)
 }
}

val strings = NumberMatcher("geo12", "neo493", "leo")
for (str <- strings) {
  str match {
  case NumberMatcher(group) => println(group)
  case _ => println("no")
}
}
}
```

we can achieve this with above code as well