# scala unapply that returns boolean

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, unapply

Reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1903341/is-it-a-rule-that-unapply-will-always-return-an-option), I still have questions about `unapply()` that returns `Boolean`.

If take a look at ***Scala Programming Book (2nd edition), page 602***. There is an example:

```
case Email(Twice(x @ UpperCase()), domain) => ...
```

Where UpperCase defined as an object that has `unapply()` returning `Boolean` and does not have `apply()`

```
object UpperCase {
 def unapply(s:String): Boolean = s.toUpperCase == s
}
```

Where `Twice` is something like this:

```
object Twice {
 def apply(s:String): String = s + s
 ...
```

**The questions are (must be too many, sorry for that):**

How does UpperCase().unapply(..) works here?

If I pass: `DIDI@hotmail.com`, then `x` in first code snippet = 'DI'.. then we use '@' ..to bind 'x' to  pass it to `UpperCase.unapply` to invoke `unapply(x)` i.e `unapply('DIDI')` (?) Then it returns `True`.

But why not `Option` ? I tend to think that `unapply` returns `Option`.. kind of one way how it works. That's probably because usually `Option` wraps some data, but for simple case we should NOT wrap boolean? And because we do not have apply()?

What the difference, when use `Boolean` / `Option` ? Based on this example.

And this syntax: `x @ UpperCase()`, is it supposed to substitute `value match case` (is that way how I suppose to read it?) syntax if we are matching inside one particular `case`? It doesn't seems as unified way/syntax of doing this.

Usually syntax like (assuming that x,y is Int): `case AA(x @ myX, y) => println("myX: " + myX)` says that `x` binds to `myX`, basically `myX` is alias to `x`.. in this case. But in our case - `x @ UpperCase()`. `x` binds to `UpperCase().unapply()`.. putting `x` as parameter. I mean binding here is quite abstract/wide notion..

Answer (score 6):

This is simple:

1) If you return **Boolean**, your unapply just tests matching query

```
scala> object UpperCase {
     | def unapply(s: String) = s.toUpperCase == s
     | }
defined module UpperCase

scala> "foo" match {
     | case UpperCase() => true
     | case _ => false
     | }
res9: Boolean = false
```

2) If you return **Option[T]**, you create an extractor, which unwraps T

```
scala> object IsUpperCase {
     | def unapply(s: String) = Option(s).map(x => x.toUpperCase == x)
     | }
defined module IsUpperCase

scala> "FOO" match {case IsUpperCase(flag) => flag}
res0: Boolean = true
```

Comment: so basically you are saying that case can work with Option (Some. None) result as good as with Boolean (true, false) result?

Comment: But what about '@' sign and this syntax around matching inside case. Do you find this unified enough? is it better than to use: value match { case SomeClass() => match {case (AnotherClass) => etc..}} ?

Comment: It should be "FOO" match {case IsUpperCase(true) => flag}
I suspect your original version returns true always.

Answer (score 2):

This is not so simple.

The behavior of "boolean test" match just changed in the latest milestone:

```
apm@mara:~/clones/scala$ ./build/pack/bin/scala
Welcome to Scala version 2.11.0-20130911-042842-a49b4b6375 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.7.0_25).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> 

scala> object OK { def unapply(s: String) = Some(s) filter (_ == "OK") }
defined object OK

scala> import PartialFunction._
import PartialFunction._

scala> cond("OK") { case OK() => true }
<console>:12: error: wrong number of patterns for object OK offering String: expected 1, found 0
              cond("OK") { case OK() => true }
                                ^
<console>:12: error: wrong number of patterns for object OK offering String: expected 1, found 0
              cond("OK") { case OK() => true }
                                  ^

scala> cond("OK") { case OK(x) => true }
res1: Boolean = true

scala> :q
```

Previously, you could use the extractor without extracting any fields, just for a "boolean test", even though the result of the `unapply` is not `Boolean`:

```
apm@mara:~/clones/scala$ scalam
Welcome to Scala version 2.11.0-M4 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.7.0_25).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> import PartialFunction._
import PartialFunction._

scala> object OK { def unapply(s: String) = Some(s) filter (_ == "OK") }
defined object OK

scala> cond("OK") { case OK() => true }
res0: Boolean = true

scala> cond("OK") { case OK(x) => true }
res1: Boolean = true
```

[Here is some discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/scala-internals/z7Xorug7QME) and [here is the change](https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/2848) in the way extractor signatures are processed.